# kendo grid row and revert css styles

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I use kendo grid jquery:

```
                        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                            detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#detailTemplate").html()),
                            detailInit: detailInit,
                            detailExpand: detailExpand,
                            detailCollapse: detailCollapse,
```

and set background color for selected row as:

```
                        function detailExpand(e) {
                            console.log('detailExpand called');
                            console.log(e.masterRow, e.detailRow);

                            var cells = e.masterRow.find("td");
                            backgroundDefault = cells.css("background-color");
                            cells.css("background-color", "#F1E5AC");
```

it works fine. But I want to revert to default color if user collapse detail template:

```
                        function detailCollapse(e){
                            var cells = e.masterRow.find("td");
                            cells.css("background-color", backgroundDefault);
                        }
```

but there are some problems with `alt` rows and if some grids with different colors on page.

How to solve this problem flexible?

Thank you!

Comment: "there are some problems" what problems? We can't help without knowing them. Also if you could add a dojo example would help us to help you. In advance, its not a good ideia to change the Grid's DOM directly, you should use custom css classes or templates for that.

Comment: You can check if the masterRow has a `k-alt` class or not and based on the outcome set the default color. To find the default color your best bet would be to inspect the DOM and the styling applied for the theme you use and get the default color for the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can add the desired styling:

```
.k-table-row.myBackground,
.k-grid .k-table-tbody > .k-table-row.myBackground:not(.k-detail-row):hover,
.k-grid .k-table-alt-row.myBackground,
.k-grid .k-table-alt-row.myBackground:not(.k-detail-row):hover{
  background-color:#F1E5AC;
}
```

and toggle it by toggling a class on detailExpand and detailColapse events:

```
detailExpand:function(e){
  e.masterRow.addClass("myBackground")
},
detailCollapse:function(e){
  e.masterRow.removeClass("myBackground")
}
```

Here's an [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/EzuBadEn).